# Does the time to train a model using keras increase linear with epoches?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, theano

Training a model in keras can go very fast. I trained the following model. To train the model with 1 epoch finishes in a few second. However, using 20 epochs it lasts half an hour or so? An epoch means how often each sample in the training set used to train the model. Therefore, I would naively expect a linear dependency. Which factors do lead to a non-linear behavior?

```
def keras_model(X_train, y_train):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
    from keras.optimizers import SGD

    model = Sequential()
    # Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
    # in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
    # here, 20-dimensional vectors.
    model.add(Dense(63, input_dim=63, init='uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(63, init='uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(22, init='uniform'))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=sgd,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, convert_labels_to_matrix(y_train),
              nb_epoch=20, batch_size=15)

    return model
```

Comment: could you please provide training logs?